# Making the course inactive in D2L using API

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a REST Api available for D2L which can be used to make a course inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an existing course, you can use the PUT method to [Update a current course offering](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#put--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-courses-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29) and set IsActive to false.

```
PUT /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/courses/(D2LID: orgUnitId)
```

It expects the following JSON object:

```
{
    "Name": "<string>",
    "Code": "<string>",
    "StartDate": "<string:UTCDateTime>|null",
    "EndDate": "<string:UTCDateTime>|null",
    "IsActive": "<boolean>"
}
```

You will likely want to retrieve the course offering information first, and then modify the IsActive flag and send back the full object data.

```
GET /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/courses/(D2LID: orgUnitId)
```